# is it important to initialize strings in c++?

Tags: c++, stdstring

Basically, I am trying to print a string by eliminating all digits  entered in a string s. But string c does not print.Also c.empty() gives a true value. Why does this happen and how to solve it ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cctype>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s;
    string c;
    getline(cin,s);
    int l=0;
    for(decltype(s.size()) i=0;i<=s.size();i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(s[i]))
        {
            c[l]=s[i];    
            l+=1;
        }
    }
    cout<<c<<endl;         //no visible output
    cout<<c.empty();       //this prints 1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c[l]=s[i];` is wrong. You need to call `resize()` first.

Comment: The loop is running one extra time.

Comment: @CinCout, fortunately, when it comes to strings, `s[s.size()]` is still valid. It just is the null character.

Comment: @RSahu Makes sense. But won't `'\0'` be appended automatically at the end of `c` after the loop ends (assuming user correctly does the memory management for`c`)? I understand there is no harm in manually adding the null character though.

Comment: @CinCout, no, it won't happen automatically.

Comment: That means if I print `c` after the loop, by running it one less time, i may get garbage?

Comment: Added resize () inside if and changed condition of loop to i <s.size () so that loop does not run an extra time. Working now. Thanks!

Comment: @CinCout, yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Other commentators have explained what's gone wrong, but you also have a simpler way of removing digits in C++!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "abc 123 abc 123 abc 123";
    std::cout << "Original: " << s << std::endl;
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
                           [](char ch) { return std::isdigit(ch); }),
            s.end());
    std::cout << "Without Digits: " << s << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Another +1 for leveraging the standard library. Though it could be a good idea to point out that you’re filtering the original string in place instead of creating a new filtered string like in the question (I’m thinking `copy_if` and `back_inserter` for that) and it depends on the context which variant you want.

Comment: Despite the elegance of the standard library and all that, I don't see how this is simple, considering OP's fluency in C++.

Comment: I understand how this works in general. Could anyone please just explain how exactly [ ](char ch) works ?

Comment: @AritraBan That is syntax for declaring a lambda / anonymous function: `[]` indicates that we shouldn't any variables, `(char ch)` is a function signature indicating that we accept a single parameter: a variable `ch` of type `char`. I believe you could replace this whole lambda function with `isdigit` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
string c; //An empty string
...
if(!isdigit(s[i]))
        {
            c[l]=s[i];
```

You have not allocated space in `c` to put characters.You could use `push_back` instead to push elements into `c`.

```
c.push_back(s[i]);
```

Or you could call `resize()` to have space allocated for `c`.

```
c.resize(s.length());
...
c[l]=s[i];    
l+=1;
```

At the end of the loop, don't forget to put a `\0`, if you run your loop till `s.size()-1`.

```
c[l]='\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

use **`operator+=`** to append the char to the string, like

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cctype>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s;
    string c;
    getline(cin,s);
    int l=0;
    for(decltype(s.size()) i=0;i<=s.size();i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(s[i]))
        {
           //Use this
           c+=s[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<c<<endl;         //no visible output
    cout<<c.empty();       //this prints 1
    return 0;
}
```